# Import Python Keras model with weights into Tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, keras, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I have some neural networks for the classification of images developed in Python 3.7 using the Keras package that is included in TensorFlow and I want to export the layers and weights model to import it in a Node.js application that uses Tensorflow.js.

I have the neural networks saved in h5 format with two separate files, one for the layer model and the other for the weights model. Try to follow this tutorial that Tensorflow proposes (https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras), but it does not work.

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import tensorflowjs as tf
import json

cnn_name = '1'

layers = './model/' + cnn_name + '/model.h5'
weights = './model/' + cnn_name + '/weights.h5'
cnn = load_model(layers)
cnn.load_weights(weights)

tf.converters.save_keras_model(cnn, './model/' + cnn_name + 'json/')

with open('./model/' + cnn_name + 'json/weights.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(tf.converters.keras_h5_conversion.h5_weights_to_tfjs_format(weights), f, cls=NumpyEncoder)
```

In Node I can load the layer file using the function tf.loadLayersModel and start the model, but I can not load the weight file. I think I have to use the loadWeights method of the model that returns the loadLayersModel function, but you have to pass a weight manifest and I do not know how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.loadLayersModel` loads the topology (model.json) and the weights file. The name of the weights file are in model.json file. However, if the weights files to be loaded are in a different folder, the property `weightPathPrefix` of the options passed as parameter can be used. It will look like as the following:

```
tf.loadLayersModel(url, {weightPathPrefix: weightFolderPath});
```

Comment: I have already tried it. Even after trying it, I thought the problem might be that I accessed a local folder and set up a file server with Node, but it doesn't work either. From what I read on the internet the problem may be that I am with a console application and does not have access to the window object from which the fetch method takes to recover some files, but I still do not understand why the model.json recovers and not the pesos that I have with him in the same folder

Comment: Did you check in the developer console, under the network tab, the request that is made to retrieve the weights?

Comment: No. I need to build an app that does not use the browser. It's a Node App executed in terminal